# Update state of a class in a recursive function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm very new to **reactjs**. Currently, I'm working on a project which needs to read some files iteratively. So I pass some files to the *fileHandlingFunction*.

```
export class MainComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    this.state = {
      imageFiles: [];
    }
  }

  fileHandlingFunction(files){ // files is an array of image files
    // iterate through the files and append them into an array in state
    this.syncIterate(files, this.syncIterate);
  }

  syncIterate(fileArray, callBackSyncIterate) {
    let tempFile = fileArray[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(tempFile);
    reader.onload = (event) => {
      this.setState({imageFiles: this.state.imageFiles.concat[reader.result]});
    }

    if (fileArray.length > 1) {
      // Removes the first element of the file array
      let updatedArray = fileArray.slice(1);
      callBackSyncIterate(updatedArray, callBackSyncIterate);
    }
  }
}
```

When I'm using a for loop to append files into the state, smaller files append first and then larger files append afterward (I strictly need to avoid this). That is the reason is to use callback functions in a recursive manner to iterate through the *files* array which is passed to *fileHandlingFunction*.

But when I try to insert image files, inside recursive function calls, I get *"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined"* error.
In this stage, we can not change the state of a component inside a recursive function call. I hope your suggestions for resolve this issue.
I really appreciate the help of yours to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think issue is that your function reads `this` as undefined. So to convert functions to arrow functions.

Comment: @PriyankKachhela I tried it with the arrow function. But then again I got the same issue. Smaller files were appended first and larger files were appended afterward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall the method into onload:

```
function fileHandlingFunction(files) { // files is an array of image files
    // iterate through the files and append them into an array in state
    let stateArray = [];
    this.syncIterate(files, stateArray, this.syncIterate);
    this.setState({imageFiles: stateArray});
}

function syncIterate(fileArray, stateArray, callBackSyncIterate) {
    let tempFile = fileArray[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(tempFile);
    reader.onload = (event) => {
        stateArray.push(reader.result);
        if (fileArray.length > 1) {
            // Removes the first element of the file array
            let updatedArray = fileArray.slice(1);
            callBackSyncIterate(updatedArray, callBackSyncIterate);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In here, the *stateArray* would be empty when updating the state as the asynchronous behavior of the javascript. 
Meanwhile, in the *stateArray*, small files would be appended first and larger files would be appended afterward for the same reason.
When *FileReader* reads the large file, the following code would be run.

Comment: What if you move the if (fileArray.length > 1) into the onLoad, after the push? In this way I think the function will be called again only after the data is loaded into the array (but it will take more time probably)

Answer (score 0):

reader.onLoad creates a new javascript context for the function itself (hence the arrow function used).
So "this" in the onload function you use is connected to only the functions context.
Try adding a variable in which you store the context of the class/component.
For example `let that = this`

```
export class MainComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    this.state = {
      imageFiles: [];
    }
  }

  fileHandlingFunction(files){ // files is an array of image files
    // iterate through the files and append them into an array in state
    this.syncIterate(files, this.syncIterate);
  }

  syncIterate(fileArray, callBackSyncIterate) {
    let that = this;
    let tempFile = fileArray[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(tempFile);
    reader.onload = (event) => {
      that.setState({imageFiles: that.state.imageFiles.concat[reader.result]});
    }

    if (fileArray.length > 1) {
      // Removes the first element of the file array
      let updatedArray = fileArray.slice(1);
      callBackSyncIterate(updatedArray, callBackSyncIterate);
    }
  }
}
```